# Capitalized Words with Regular Expression

Tags: regex

I'm new to RegEx and I'm looking for a way to match sentences where the first letter is capitalized and the rest is in lowercase.

I've tried a couple of things (IF statements included), but just can't seem to get it.

This is my last version:

```
(([A-Z])([a-z]+\s|[a-z]+))+
```

I thought it worked at first, but is now accepting capitalized letters in the middle of the word.

The Output Would Be Like This (Each Word Capitalized).

Thanks!!

Answer (score 7):

**To match whole strings** that start with an uppercase letter and then have no uppercase letters use

```cs
^[A-Z][^A-Z]*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Q48COs/1). `^` matches the start of string, `[A-Z]` matches the uppercase letters, `[^A-Z]*` matches 0 or more chars other than uppercase letters and `$` matches the end of string.

**To match capitalized words**, you may use

```cs
\b[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*\b
```

where `\b` stands for [**word boundaries**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html). See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/B4TIJZ/1).

In various regex flavors, there are other ways to match word boundaries:

- [bash](/questions/tagged/bash),[r](/questions/tagged/r) (TRE, base R): `\<[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*\>`
- [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql), [tcl](/questions/tagged/tcl): `\m[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*\M` or `\y[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*\y`
- [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) (MySQL versions before 8): `[[:<:]][A-Z][a-zA-Z]*[[:>:]]`

Also, you may consider using `[[:upper:]]` or `\p{Lu}` instead of `[A-Z]` and `[[:alpha:]]` or `\p{L}` instead of `[a-zA-Z]` to match any Unicode uppercase letters or any letters correspondingly.

See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/B4TIJZ/2) and [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/B4TIJZ/3), too.

Answer (score 6):

The expression accepts capital letters in the middle of the world because now the spaces between words are optional, and words can run into each other.

You can take a more structured approach: a sentence must have at least one word. That's

```
[A-Z][a-z]*
```

After that initial word you can get any number of more words, each preceded by whitespace. So in total:

```
[A-Z][a-z]*(\s[A-Z][a-z]*)*
```